# Performance issues of Numpy under WSL2

Tags: performance, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I've setup WSL2 (with the default Ubuntu distribution) on Windows 11 and installed Numpy via apt, with `sudo apt install python3-numpy` (and lots of other dependencies). When testing the performance of Numpy under WSL2, it is coming up as ~50x slower. It's just a simple test with a dot product (code below, adapted from [Markus Beuckelmann](https://gist.github.com/markus-beuckelmann/8bc25531b11158431a5b09a45abd6276)), but based on what I've seen online, this should not happen at all. With larger matrices and more iterations it becomes worse and worse.

I haven't found anyone online complaining about such performance issues; some even say that WSL2 runs faster than Windows (!). What could be the problem in my WSL2 installation?

```
np.random.seed(0)

size = 1000
A, B = np.random.random((size, size)), np.random.random((size, size))

# Matrix multiplication
N = 5
t = time()
for i in range(N):
    np.dot(A, B)
delta = time() - t
print('Dotted two %dx%d matrices in %0.5f s.' % (size, size, delta / N))
del A, B
```

Native Windows: ~0.01s

WSL2: ~0.57s

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem: I had not installed Intel's MKL libraries for accelerating low-level linear algebra operations (BLAS and LAPACK). They come pre-configured in Anaconda installations, which is what I used on Windows. To solve this, either [install Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/) on WSL2 (so it becomes your default Python environment) or install Intel MKL's libraries with the command below (and let them replace the BLAS and LAPACK libraries when asked during installation):

```
sudo apt install libmkl-dev
```

The performance drop in WSL2 for Numpy is now around 10% (or less in some cases), which is acceptable for me.

Comment: One quick additional comment: I've since fixed an inconsistency in my benchmark code and now the performance difference is negligible, making WSL2's performance practically identical to native code.